# javascript while loop giving different results in node and browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, while-loop, firebug

I am executing the following seemingly straightforward code

```
var number = 0;
while (number <= 12) {
    console.log(number);
    number = number + 2;  
}
```

and I am getting different results in the browser and in Node.
When I run it in the Firebug(v 2.0.4 ) console on Firefox(v. 32.0.3) the result I get is

0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14

which is not`the result I expected.

In Node, the same code gives me the correct answer which is

0
2
4
6
8
10
12

Is there anything I'm missing regarding the behaviour in the browser???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't reproduce, Firefox 32.

Comment: Could it be that you are seeing `14 0 2 4 6 8 10 12`? The 14 seems to be kind of the "result" of the loop (I guess because of the assignment in the loop body). Just like `1 + 1` prints `2`. This is in FF 32.0.3. I can't tell yoy why FF is doing that though.

Comment: Can't reproduce either, outside of what @FelixKling described.  Are you sure you're seeing the `14` on the end?

Comment: After the loop the console is printing the value of the last evaluated expression, which is `number = number + 2`.

Comment: You can reproduce by copy-pasting the entire code to the JS console, at least in Chrome.

Comment: Oh wow, indeed, Chrome prints `14` in the end. Then I guess it's because of how `console.log` calls are handled by the browser. Also I didn't know that the console typically prints the result of the last expression inside a loop. The more you know... @Juhana.

Comment: And I just noticed that you mention Firebug. I guess Firebug and the built in console work slightly differently wrt `console.log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run a script in Firebug's console, then it will **evaluate** the code. So it's evaluating the value of the **last number** in the while loop (which is now 14) and prints that out. It's actually printing out the value of `number` 8 times but groups them in 1 print out.

You can see the same effect by just typing in "window" in the command line. It's evaluating it's value and prints it out in the console.

More info can be found in the description to [Firebug's command line](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line).

Answer (score 2):

If you slightly change your code:

**CHROME**

```
var number = 0;
while (number <= 12) {
    console.log("z" + number);
    number = number + 2;  
}

z0
z2
z4
z6
z8
z10
z12
14
```

You'll see that the `14` is not being printed by the loop.  Rather, that is the end value of the expression when the loop finishes running and is printed by the console itself.

**FIREFOX**

```
while (number <= 12) {
    console.log("z" + number);
    number = number + 2;  
}

14
"z0"
"z2"
"z4"
"z6"
"z8"
"z10"
"z12"
```

In Firefox, it runs the entire loop, prints the result and then catches up with the console.

Comment: I have tried it in Firebug and it gives the same results as Chrome. How can I avoid printing out the 14?

Comment: Running inside the console?  You can't.  Run it inside of a page or something.